# When disabling the firewire-driver in Windows will this too disable firewire connected through a PCMCIA device?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, firewire, pcmcia

The broader overarching question (not seeking an answer to this, but wanted to provide context) is how do I ensure that laptops running Microsoft Windows 7 and exposing DMA-ports (eg. firewire) are disabled once the operating system have loaded.

Preventing the Firewire-driver from loading once Windows have booted works as expected, but I've been unable to confirm whether this too will disable a Firewire-port exposed through a PCMCIA-card.

My question is hence whether disabling the Firewire-driver will also prevent a Firewire-port exposed through a PCMCIA from functioning?

Answer (score 1):

It has been my experience that installing supported (no driver disk required) PCMCIA or Express Cards will load and bind the Firewire driver to the new hardware even if the driver was disabled for the built-in Firewire port.

In Windows Server 2008/Vista and above you should be able to use Group Policy to disable devices by their type.  MS TechNet info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731665.aspx